# Can I turn an existing asparagus bed into raised bed?

Tags: vegetables, raised-beds, asparagus

My wife and I planted some asparagus last spring in a regular bed next to an outbuilding.  We are looking to add another plant right next to the asparagus, which I would like to put into a simple raised bed.  I'll probably just use some treated 2-bys as my bed walls.

I was thinking that it probably would not hurt to just put the asparagus into an attached raised bed as well.

Can I add the raised bed around the asparagus and fill it in with soil? This would in effect bury the asparagus roots by 6-8" more than what they already are.

Comment: Did you ever try this? How did it go?

Answer (score 2):

**Do not replant an old asparagus bed with new asparagus plants.** Choose fresh ground to avoid build-up of diseases. An open, sunny site is best, but asparagus will tolerate dappled shade.

Asparagus grows on most soil types provided they are well drained. **On heavy soils consider creating raised beds**.

A pH of 6.5-7.5 is ideal, so more acidic soils may need liming.

Clear the ground of perennial weeds and incorporate at least one bucketful of organic matter such as garden compost or well-rotted farmyard manure every square metre (yard).

[image: Asparagus]
[more about Asparagus](http://apps.rhs.org.uk/advicesearch/profile.aspx?pid=310)